# How can I delete a file named "--append"?

Tags: rm, options, coreutils

By mistake I have created a file named : `--append`.

How do I delete it?

Simply entering the usual command, `rm -f --append`, doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this in-order to remove the file:

```
rm -- --append
```

Comment: The other approach is `rm ./--append`